# Possible to get string value from corresponding integer value - like Enum but not Enum - used for lookup

Tags: javascript, enums, reverse

Is it possible to get this to work?

```
 var DaysList = {1:"monday", 2:"tuesday", 3:"wednesday"}
 alert(DaysList .1);
```

I want to prevent using a switch case statement in order to get the value (E.g. Monday where I have the ID of 1)

This is not the real world problem, just an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use square brackets to access DaysList object properties:

```
var DaysList = {1:"monday", 2:"tuesday", 3:"wednesday"};
alert(DaysList[1]); // Alerts "monday"
alert(DaysList[2]); // Alerts "tuesday"
```